# The use if the future progressive in context

Tags: future-continuous

Tell me please if the following use of the future progressive is correct.

> If I am using my phone, that doesn't meant that I will be ignoring you. What that means is that I will be checking some information.

Would the use of the present progressive be better? For example:

> If am using my phone, that doesn't meant that I am ignoring you. What that means is that I am  checking some information.

The context is that I tell students that if they see me using my phone, that only means that I'm checking some info.

Comment: *If am* is always wrong. It should be *If **I** am*. And you're mixing present and future tenses in a way that's unnatural. Either put everything in the present or everything in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the present progressive because it matches the first sentence...  Very short version:

> If I am using my phone, I am checking some information

And a longer version:

> If I am using my phone, it doesn't meant I am ignoring you, it means I am checking some information.

If you're looking for future progressive, you should turn it around:

> I will be checking some information, so if you see me using my phone, it does not mean I am ignoring you.